# fors in python list comprehension

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, for-loop, list-comprehension

Consider I have nested for loop in python list comprehension

```
>>> data = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
>>> [y for x in data for y in x]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> [y for y in x for x in data]
[6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8]
```

I can't explain why is that when i change the order of two `fors`

```
for y in x
```

What's `x` in second list comprehension?

Comment: Maybe it's worth pointing out that this discrepancy doesn't happen in `ipython` terminal though. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's holding the value of the previous comprehsension. Try inverting them, you'll get an error

```
>>> data = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
>>> [y for y in x for x in data]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

To further test it out, print `x` and see

```
>>> [y for x in data for y in x]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> x
[6, 7, 8]
>>> [y for y in x for x in data]
[6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8]
```

Comment: OH,I SEE !! `[y for y in x for x in data]` So the nested `x` won't change the value of outer `x` , in another way , `for x in data` is not working. Am I right? But wouldn't the result be `[6,7,8]`?

Comment: @MMMMMCCLXXVII I'm not sure if I follow. The list comprehension does not provide a new scope. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules).

Answer (score 3):

The list comprehensions are as:

```
[y for x in data for y in x]
[y for y in x for x in data]
```

A `for` loop conversion of `[y for y in x for x in data]` is:

```
for y in x:
    for x in data:
        y
```

Here `x` is holding the last updated value of `x` of your previous list comprehension which is:

```
[6, 7, 8]
```